# Knowing that the probability to drill success (produced) exploratory hydrocarbon well is $0.2$ by certain company

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Knowing that the probability to drill success (produced) exploratory hydrocarbon well is $0.2$ by certain company, this company has drilled four success exploratory wells in different areas on the last three drilling activity.

What is the probability of the next well to be dry? Why

My try:

$P(B \cap A) = \dfrac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)} = \dfrac{0.8(0.2)^4}{0.2^4}$.

Is that correct?

Comment: If we assume independence (perhaps not fully justifiable, but reasonable) then the probability is $0.8$.

Comment: this company has drilled four success exploratory wells in different areas on the last three drilling activity .

Comment: I guess I don't get it. But Andre seems to. I would listen to him.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that the events "success" on various trials are *independent*. Then the probability of success on the next trial is what it always is, namely $0.2$, so the probability of a dry well is $0.8$.

Your calculation, which is a little more complicated than necessary, implicitly assumes independence. For to find $\Pr(A)$, you took the fourth power of the probability of success on any one trial, and to find $\Pr(A\cap B)$, you found the product of $\Pr(A)$ and $\Pr(B)$. It gives the correct result.